# Multiple buttons in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Will something like this work? If it does, how do I determine which button was clicked on post?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdatePanel" runat="server"><ContentTemplate><div class="home_c" id="home_c2">

            <div class="home-tabs">
                <asp:Button CssClass="home_tab" ClientIDMode="static" Text="Cures" ID="cures_btn" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button CssClass="home_tab" ClientIDMode="static" Text="Conditions" ID="conditions_btn" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button CssClass="home_tab" ClientIDMode="static" Text="Recent" ID="recent_btn" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button CssClass="home_tab" ClientIDMode="static" Text="Uncured" ID="uncured_btn" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div class="home-search">

            </div>

        </div>    
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Well, there is an obvious way to find out - just try it! As to which - you can give each button a handler, and use `sender` parameter there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work. Just add `OnClick` events for each and have your click events defined in your code behind to handle them. Simple as that. :)

E.g.

```
<asp:Button CssClass="home_tab" ClientIDMode="static" Text="Cures" ID="cures_btn" runat="server" OnClick="cures_btn_Click" />
```

And in your code behind

```
protected void cures_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some code
}
```